# How can a folder size be larger than it's size on disk?

Tags: file, size, ntfs

I have this interesting test case where I generated thousands and thousands of very small files. As you might imagine the size on disk grew linearly but I did not expect that the size on disk would be less than the size of the entire folder. (NTFS)

I understand how the size on disk can be greater than the size, but I'm confused as to how it could be smaller.

I'm not exactly sure how this is possible. Any clues?

[image]

Comment: Is Windows/NTFS doing some in-place compression or file compensation for redundant files?

For anyone interested in how I did this here's the batch file:

https://pastebin.com/FgWVJsiJ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be either the compression, or see [sparse files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/sparse-files).

But in your case, I'd guess that's the third option - if the file is small, usually under 400 bytes, its data can fit into MFT File Record, so it doesn't occupy any cluster. You have ~30.000 files, so if they are approximately 300 bytes each, it can be 9 MB and still it would count as 0 bytes on disk:
[image]

Comment: Oh yea! I totally forgot that in the newer NTFS standard(s) if the file is small enough to fit in the filesystem's addressing schema the data is actually placed there. Derp thanks!

Comment: Actually it's there from the very beginning :) It's called resident attribute - if attribute data are stored in MFT, and non-resident attribute - if data are stored on disk in clusters.

Comment: Its been a long time since I genuinely learned something new and useful. Thanks!!

Comment: Your link looks to be broken. Does this also explain why a folder on my machine that has 600GB of video content but Windows 11 reports the size on disk being ~335GB? Is there a file with empty contents?

Comment: @IanSmith The link @ Microsoft had changed, I corrected it to its new location. I can imagine situation when some video software creates 600GB temp file as a sparse file, but if it's a normal video content, it can't be the case, normal video files have (very) high entropy.